# need equivalent PHP (HttpWebRequest and Stream or curl) code for this .net code

Tags: php

i got a problem in PHP. i want to get all the bus stations in india. so i have made an xml request and post that xml data to given API URL. but i did not get the result. below is the .net code which is working fine. even i have used the "HttpRequest" method in php, but it gives me an error like "Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found".

can anybody help me to give me the equivalent code in php or possible ways to get the data..?

thanks in advance.

## .net code (working fine)

```
protected void getBusServices(string journeydate)
{

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        StringReader stream;
        StreamReader reader;
        XmlTextReader textreader;
        HttpWebRequest req;
        HttpWebResponse response;
        try
        {

            string password = "password";
            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(journeydate);
            string strJrneyDate = dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
            string strRtDate = dt.AddDays(3).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
            string url = Bus_Api_Url;


             string RequestCommand = "<Command>GET_STATIONS</Command> <Username>username</Username> <Password>password</Password>";
            req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            string RequestData = "RequestXML=<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?><BusRequest  xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>" + RequestCommand + "</BusRequest>";
            req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
            req.ContentLength = RequestData.Length;
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.Write(RequestData);
            }
            response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            Stream responsestream = response.GetResponseStream();
            reader = new StreamReader(responsestream);
            string xmlresponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
            stream = new StringReader(xmlresponse);
            textreader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
            doc.LoadXml(xmlresponse);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(textreader);


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EBUtils.Logger.LogError.Publish(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            reader = null;
            // stream = null;
            reader = null;
            response = null;
            doc = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com? Btw try [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: You want to parse xml?

Comment: i tried with php curl functions. but did not get the result. API provider told me that, you have to use "HttpWebRequest" and Stream functions to write the request data. so that only the request is valid and we will give you the result

Answer (score 0):

its really simple, check out  http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

i've used the same method lot of times, heres a little snippet from one of my active php projects.

```
$file = "http://the_address_of_the_xml_file.com";
if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file)) {
return 0;
} else {     //open
$status = $xml->attributes()->statu
if($status=='ok') {//open
$bio = $xml->artist->bio;


//closed
for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {
```

and how about file_get_content ?

```
$post_data = array('xml' => $xml_str);
$stream_options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' . "\r\n",
        'content' =>  http_build_query($post_data)));

$context  = stream_context_create($stream_options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, null, $context);
```

ha im not on top form today, in bed really unwell ;)

Comment: You missed the part about posting data.

Comment: thanks for you response. but Sorry Guernica. i dont want to read an xml file. instead i want to send an xml data (contains request type)  to the given API URL and get the response from them. then i can parse it easily.