# Visit an url without showing

Tags: php, ajax, iframe, cron

I have a Cronjob which is done every ten minutes on my site, for example on the page http://www.example.com/example.php

Sometimes, in the administration panel of my website, when the admin have made some modification, i want to automatically launch the script on example.php.

So my question is : Is there a way to visit an url, without showing it ? My goal is that the server read the page, not the admin, because the example files can be very heavy.

I have read this thread, but it's not clear to me :
[How can I simulate a visit to a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127510/how-can-i-simulate-a-visit-to-a-url)

Thanks you for your advice !

Comment: wouldn't curl do the job? if not look at simplexml_load_file. read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785735/need-equivalent-php-httpwebrequest-and-stream-or-curl-code-for-this-net-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP - curl 
make a standard code and with the single you can upload data to server..
http://coderscult.com/php-curl-tutorial-and-example/

Comment: Thanks ! I thought it was a easier way to do that, but it works :) Many thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can use wget/curl to silently grab the content of a page.

```
wget -O – -q http://example.com/urltofetch.html >/dev/null 2>&1
```